# ios 7: Low memory & game crashes

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am developing a game which crashes due to low memory. I checked memory by profiling and saw that memory allocation was increasing while I was doing nothing in the game, then I run the project again - the issue was same: memory allocation was increasing with time while I wasn't tapping even a single button

[image: at 9.08 live bytes was 27.67 MB]

After 5 mints live bytes was 36.15 MB

[image]

Can anyone please explain this behaviour?

Comment: Most likely you have a memory leak. Find the leak, fix it.

Comment: Can you provide more informations? Are you using any kind of framework to develop the game (i.e. cocos2d)? Do you find this bug to happen only on simulator, device or both? From the screenshot it is clear that the bleed is caused by IOAccelResource (UIAccelerometer), can you provide code for the relevant sections?

Comment: @AntonioE. Yes I am using cocos2d and accelerometer is not used in this game

Comment: Cocos2d internally uses accelerometer. You can try removing any reference to the accelerometer from Cocos2d and see what happens